# Маска из текстуры

Tags: unity3d

Всем добрый день!
Допустим у нас есть черно-белая текстура. Можно ли сделать из неё что-то типа маски, что-бы черным участкам соответствовал один материал, а белым - другой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам это нужно для 2d или для 3d объекта?

В первом случае вы можете использовать [Sprite Renderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-SpriteRenderer.html) и его параметр mask interaction, который отвечает за то, как этот спрайт взаимодействует с маской. А для того чтобы добавить маску используйте объект с компонентом [Sprite Masks](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteMask.html).

В документации по ссылкам вы сможете найти примеры.

Если вам нужно это для 3d объекта, то единственный вариант - писать свой шейдер.

Comment: Для 3D объекта. Спасибо за совет, почитаю про шейдеры